# MySQL GROUP BY not empty rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a query which returns:

```
uid  | text    | flag | nonuid | another_id
123  | "tree"  | 1    | 176    | 7098
456  | "apple" | 1    | 321    | 9686
321  | "apple" | 0    |        | 5675
847  | "tree"  | 1    | 176    | 6456
993  | "car"   | 1    | 332    | 9686
222  | "cat"   | 0    |        | 7098
913  | "car"   | 0    |        | 2301
176  | "tree"  | 0    |        | 6456
982  | "car"   | 1    | 332    | 7098
332  | "car"   | 0    |        | 7321

uid: unique field for every record
text: not unique piece of text
flag: whenever this is a "repost" entry of another row
nonuid: uid of the original of the repost
another_id: process_id that created the entry
```

I need to "collapse this list, so that `nonuid` appears only once in the list. If the field is empty, then there is no repost, so the entire row should be displayed. So after running the "right" query I should see the same list like this:

```
uid  | text    | flag | nonuid | another_id: GROUP_CONCAT(another_id)
123  | "tree"  | 1    | 176    | 7098,6456
456  | "apple" | 1    | 321    | 9686
321  | "apple" | 0    |        | 5675
993  | "car"   | 1    | 332    | 9686,7098
222  | "cat"   | 0    |        | 7098
993  | "car"   | 0    |        | 9686
176  | "tree"  | 0    |        | 6456
332  | "car"   | 0    |        | 7321
```

I could `GROUP BY` the list by `text`, but `uid` **332** and `uid` **222** have same text, while both not being a repost - and I should keep the original and the repost. Alternatively I could collapse by `nonuid`, which also fails, since all the "empty" nonuid become grouped together.

Comment: And why not group by both `text` and `nonuid`?

Comment: @Sirko . . . You should write that as an answer.

Comment: why you need to select 993 car and not 982 car? is there any field that defines the order?

Comment: @fthiella Not really. As soon as there is only one `nonuid` field occurence and another_id is a group concat - it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use `GROUP BY` on both columns you need?

```
SELECT `text`, `nonuid`, GROUP_CONCAT( `another_id`)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY `text`, `nonuid`;
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cfeb/2/0)**

<sup>You have not specified, how to select the other columns, so I omitted them here</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you want to complete two queries, one containing all the entries which are original (flag=0) and a second where flag=1, which are then grouped by nonuid with the group concat, so you could create the quiers seperately and then union the two results.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FLAG = 0
UNION
SELECT min(uid),text,flag,nonuid,GROUP_CONCAT(another_ID) 
    FROM table WHERE flag = 1 GROUP BY nonuid
```

Here min(uid) in the second query would give you the first repost uid. I don't think you specify which uid you wanted from the grouping.

Comment: This might work as good, but my original query has about 10 outer joins to fetch additional information. Duplicating those joins will be too expensive.

Comment: The next question is could you ever have two non-reposted entries that have the same text? In that instance the nonuid would be empty and the text would be the same and you would lose a row potentially?